# Greek letters in axes labels are not working

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, tex

I'm trying to use Greek letters in my xlabel of a plot. Every solution on the internet says that Matlab will accept tex. But instead of the delta-symbol my x-axis is simply labeled 'D'

```
a = plot(0:40, y);
hold on

plot(delta_T,brechkraft, 'x')
errorbar(delta_T, brechkraft,delta_b,'x');

title('2mm Oelschicht');


xlabel('\Delta');
ylabel('Brechkraft D in 1/cm');
annotation('textbox', [.2 .8 .1 .1],...
    'String', {'Fit: f(x) = m*x + b',    ['m = ', num2str(p(1)) ],    ['b = ', num2str(p(2)) ]});
shg
hold off

saveas(a, 'abc1.png','png');
```

Comment: Does whatever default font Matlab uses on your system definitely have a glyph for Delta? Have you tried different fonts?

Comment: What was the reason finally?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402479/how-to-prevent-matlab-printing-false-space-and-use-wrong-fonts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a little curious, your syntax seems alright. Have you screwed up some fonts of your system? Or maybe your `'interpreter'` is set to `none` ([doc text props](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html))?

Check it with (`hx` = handle of xlabel):

```
get(hx, 'Interpreter')
```

and set it with:

```
set(hx, 'Interpreter', 'tex')
```

If that is not working, as a first workaround you could try to activate the **Latex interpreter** instead of the usually default `tex`.

```
x = 0:40;
y = x.^2;

plot(y,x, 'x')
title('\alpha \beta \gamma');

hx = xlabel('Symbol $\sqrt{\Delta}$  ','interpreter','latex');
hy = ylabel('Symbol $\sqrt{\epsilon}$','interpreter','latex');
```

[image]

---

**But actually for simple greek letters, that is not necessary!**

with the default `tex` interpreter:

```
hx = xlabel('\Delta');
hy = ylabel('\epsilon');
```

is working too:

[image]

but used with latex syntax `delta` is not recognized anymore:

```
xlabel('Symbol $\sqrt{\Delta}$  ','interpreter','tex');
ylabel('Symbol $\sqrt{\epsilon}$','interpreter','tex');
```

---

**Other ideas:**

What font does it return when you type: `get(0,'DefaultAxesFontName')`?
Does it work when you set it to **Helvetica** or **Arial**?

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontName','Helvetica');
```

It is also reported that on some systems (e.g. **Ubuntu** 12.xx) you need to install **tex fonts** first.