# Subscripts plotted with text function are not displayed properly

Tags: matlab, text, matlab-figure

I'm trying to add a text box to a figure.  I'm using:

```
figure
semilogy([3 10],[1E-10 1E5],'o'); hold on
mylabel('10,000/T (1/K)','R_{c} (kmol/m^2)','Carbon Reaction Rates')
text(4,1E3,'R_c =  2R_{s2}+R_{s3}=2k_2[Y_{O2}]+k_3[Y_{CO2}]','interpreter','tex')
```

and I get the following result with no subscripts:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, apart from `text(0.5,0.5,'X_{c}','interpreter','none')`, but you stated the interpreter would have been set properly to `'tex'`. It seems you have the same problem like the dude in [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103033/greek-letters-in-axes-labels-are-not-working/21103117#21103117).

Comment: I added the actual code I'm using (minus data) and the plot output I get.  The link you suggested seems similar, but not sure if it applies since that was for labels and this uses the text command.  I did try and play with the font as one of the comments suggested, but it didnt help.

Comment: It works here too (I have R2014b)